# "C#/Xaml Windows app store" Get a file.mbtiles on a localhost using nodejs

Tags: c#, node.js, windows

I wanna use a tile map in my c# program using a nodejs server.
The server is actually working because I can see tiles on my browser.
The problem is that my program correctly works on Visual Studio but when I'm trying to use the packaged version on a different device it doesn't recognize my server.
Here is my actual code :

```
        public MapPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.navigationHelper = new NavigationHelper(this);
        this.navigationHelper.LoadState += navigationHelper_LoadState;
        this.navigationHelper.SaveState += navigationHelper_SaveState;
        MapTileLayer layer2 = new MapTileLayer();
        layer2.Opacity = 1;
        string ip = this.getCurrentIPAddress().ToString();
        layer2.GetTileUri += (s, e) =>
        {
            e.Uri = new Uri(string.Format("http://localhost:3000/{0}/{1}/{2}.png", e.LevelOfDetail, e.X, e.Y));
        };
        MyMap.TileLayers.Add(layer2);
        shapeLayer = new MapLayer();
        MyMap.Children.Add(shapeLayer);
        poiLayer = new MapLayer();
        MyMap.Children.Add(poiLayer);
        this.all_btn.IsChecked = true;
    }
```

Does anyone got an idea ?
Thanks for reading =)

EDIT:
It seems to be caused by the absence of Visual Studio on the device

EDIT2:
I tried to do the same process using the new VS2015 Xaml controller MapControl And I had the same issue.

EDIT3:
I went back to w8.1 and it seems that for the app to work I've to install VS and download the bing maps SDK so it may be due to this =/